# HOw to find range of IP address using grep command

Tags: linux

I need to find range of ip address from my lease file. I am trying to use this

less /var/lib/dhcpd/ | grep 
say the range is from 192.23.253.2 to 192.23.253.100

what command will work for this

Comment: [link](http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-192-23-0-0-1/pft)ARIN results for 192.23</A> shows Schlumberger IT Security Operations.  More generic options include 192.0.2 or 198.51.100 or 203.0.113 (per IETF RFC 3330 and IETF RFC 5735), or perhaps IETF BCP 5 (RFC 1918) addresses (as shown in moonbutt74's answer).

Answer (score 3):

I feel that `awk` is a more flexible tool for this task.  Python could be used as well, but you would have to write the script instead of copying and pasting a command the terminal.  You will have to change the regex patterns, record separators and field separators so they will work on your file.  If you can provide an example from your file (with sensitive data removed or changed) I will edit this answer.

Test file (copied from another SO example and tweaked):

```
lease 192.23.253.2 {
    starts 6 2009/06/27 00:40:00;
    ends 6 2009/06/27 12:40:00;
    hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:00;
    uid 00:00:00:00:00:00;
    client-hostname "examle-workstation1";
}
lease 192.23.253.3 {
    starts 6 2009/06/27 00:40:00;
    ends 6 2009/06/27 12:40:00;
    hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:00;
    uid 00:00:00:00:00:00;
    client-hostname "examle-workstation1";
}
lease 192.23.253.4 {
    starts 6 2009/06/27 00:40:00;
    ends 6 2009/06/27 12:40:00;
    hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:00;
    uid 00:00:00:00:00:00;
    client-hostname "examle-workstation1";
}
lease 192.23.253.5 {
    starts 6 2009/06/27 00:40:00;
    ends 6 2009/06/27 12:40:00;
    hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:00;
}
lease 192.23.253.6 {
    starts 6 2009/06/27 00:40:00;
    ends 6 2009/06/27 12:40:00;
    hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:01;
    uid 00:00:00:00:00:01;
    client-hostname "examle-workstation2";
}
lease 192.23.253.7 {
    starts 6 2009/06/27 00:40:00;
    ends 6 2009/06/27 12:40:00;
    hardware ethernet 01:00:00:00:00:00;
}
```

If you want the whole record:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{
      RS="lease"
      FS=" {+|;\n"
  }{
      n=split($1, a, ".")
      last=int(a[n])
      if( 3 <= last && last <= 6){
          print
      }
  }' testfile
```

What is happening in this`awk` statement:

- Set the record separator value: `RS="lease"`.
- Set the field separator value to look for `{` preceded by a space or `;\n`: `FS=" {+|;\n"`.
- Split the first field in each record at any `.`, store resulting array in `a`, store the length of `a` in `n`.
- Store the last element of `a` in `last`.
- Test if `last` is equal to or less than our minimum (2) or if `last` is equal to or greater than our maximum (6), if this is true, print the entire record.

Results:

```
 192.23.253.3 {
    starts 6 2009/06/27 00:40:00;
    ends 6 2009/06/27 12:40:00;
    hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:00;
    uid 00:00:00:00:00:00;
    client-hostname "examle-workstation1";
}

192.23.253.4 {
    starts 6 2009/06/27 00:40:00;
    ends 6 2009/06/27 12:40:00;
    hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:00;
    uid 00:00:00:00:00:00;
    client-hostname "examle-workstation1";
}

192.23.253.5 {
    starts 6 2009/06/27 00:40:00;
    ends 6 2009/06/27 12:40:00;
    hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:00;
}

192.23.253.6 {
    starts 6 2009/06/27 00:40:00;
    ends 6 2009/06/27 12:40:00;
    hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:01;
    uid 00:00:00:00:00:01;
    client-hostname "examle-workstation2";
}
```

If you want the IP addresses only:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{
     RS="lease"
     FS=" {+|;\n"
  }{
      n=split($1, a, ".")
      last=int(a[n])
      if( 3 <= last && last <= 6){
          ip=gensub(/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+).*/,"\\1","", $1)
          print ip
      }
  }' testfile
```

What is happening in this`awk` statement:

- Set the record separator value: `RS="lease"`.
- Set the field separator value to look for `{` preceded by a space or `;\n`: `FS=" {+|;\n"`.
- Split the first field in each record at any `.`, store the resulting array in `a`, store the length of `a` in `n`.
- Store the last element of `a` in `last`.
- Test if `last` is equal to or less than our minimum (2) or if `last` is equal to or greater than our maximum (6), if this is true, use the `gensub` method to strip out everything aside from the IP address using a regex pattern.

Results:

```
192.23.253.3
192.23.253.4
192.23.253.5
192.23.253.6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
less /var/lib/dhcpd/ | grep 192\.23\.253\. |grep -vi 192\.23\.253\.1\s |grep -vi 192\.23\.253\.2[0-9][0-9] |grep -vi 192\.23\.253\.1[0-9][1-9] |grep -vi 192\.23\.253\.1[1-9]0 |grep -vi 192\.23\.253\.0
```

There grep only.

Comment: Wouldn't the grep -vi 1[0-9][1-9]$ filter out .100?  (Besides, he did ask for a range that is different than 192.168.)  Also, based on the output shown in moonbutt74's answer, it seems that the IP address does not appear at the end of a line, so the use of $ may not work as you were intending.

Comment: Notice the second [1-9] so 0 is excluded. I fully tested it and 100 does work, unless I made a copy and paste error, but I don't think I did.  I fixed the range and will do something about end-of-line

Comment: Fixed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, something like this?

```
root@kali:/var/lib/dhcp# sed -n -e '/20:40:42/,/12:25:01/p' dhclient-ce17152e-8364-40bd-a3d9-5d916e421dc3-wlan0.lease | grep "expire" > narc.txt && cat narc.txt
  expire 5 2015/08/14 20:40:42;
  expire 6 2015/08/15 12:25:01;
```

So,

```
root@kali:/var/lib/dhcp# sed -n -e '/<range-from-start>/,/<range-to-end>/p' <EXACT-LOCATION-AND-FILENAME> | grep "<beginning-line-entry-of-lease-file>" > <output-file> && cat <output-file>
  expire 5 2015/08/14 20:40:42;
  expire 6 2015/08/15 12:25:01;
```

The lease from my pc file looks like this

```
lease {
  interface "wlan0";
  fixed-address 192.168.254.25;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option dhcp-lease-time 86400;
  option routers 192.168.254.254;
  option dhcp-message-type 5;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 192.168.254.254;
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.254.254;
  option dhcp-renewal-time 43200;
  option dhcp-rebinding-time 75600;
  option broadcast-address 192.168.254.255;
  option host-name "kali";
  option domain-name "netgear.com";
  renew 5 2015/08/14 08:37:20;
  rebind 5 2015/08/14 17:40:42;
  expire 5 2015/08/14 20:40:42;
}
lease {
  interface "wlan0";
  fixed-address 192.168.254.25;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option routers 192.168.254.254;
  option dhcp-lease-time 86400;
  option dhcp-message-type 5;
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.254.254;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 192.168.254.254;
  option dhcp-renewal-time 43200;
  option broadcast-address 192.168.254.255;
  option dhcp-rebinding-time 75600;
  option host-name "kali";
  option domain-name "netgear.com";
  renew 6 2015/08/15 00:05:34;
  rebind 6 2015/08/15 09:25:01;
  expire 6 2015/08/15 12:25:01;
}
```

I don't think pulling just the digits will work without grepping for the "tag" they come under.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get a minimum and maximum like this using a grep. You probably can do this with a small awk "program"